# OnResuming does not fire when opening app through Task Switcher Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

There are several ways of entering an already open app in Windows Phone 8.1, and one of them is to open the Task Switcher and select the app.
Supposedly, the `OnResuming` event should fire when this happens, as it does when you click a tile or the app in the app list if the app is in background. However, when you enter the app through the Task Switcher, no event seems to be raised, none whatsoever.
I've tried the `OnLaunched`, `OnResuming`, `RootFrame_FirstNavigated`, `OnActivated` and `OnWindowCreated`. None of these is triggered when I open the app through the Task Switcher.
So my question is, how can I know that the user entered the app through the Task Switcher?

Comment: Are you using the VS debugger/w emulator or an actual device?

Comment: Actual device and emulator, same on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this tutorial helped with my app resuming problem 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/07

Comment: I was missing the part that I had to suspend the app from VS. Thanks!